# Is lightweight migration needed when changing validation rules in Core Data

Tags: ios, validation, core-data, migration, persistence

I know that lightweight migration can handle those things :

- Adding or removing an entity, attribute, or relationship
- Making an attribute non-optional with a default value
- Making a non-optional attribute optional

But do we need lightweight migration for changing validation rules?

And how to handle situation where we have defined something like this:

Attribute is integer and its minimum value is 0 and maximum is 100. And there are some values from 0 to 100 added to persistent store. Then we change rule that sets minimum to 20 and maximum to 50 for that attribute.

How will Core Data answer to this change because now there would be some data with invalid values? How to handle this if needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no, you need **not** up the Core Data model version and using lightweight migration if you just want to include the new validation rules. Changing the validation rules will not change the model, so it will open just fine.

For old data that does not conform to the validation, nothing should happen at first. Core Data does not touch the records it does not need to change. The validation is typically triggered during the `save` operation.

That means that the next time you save you **will** get a validation error. One solution would be to iterate through all affected data upon app start after changing the validation rules and `save` before making any additional changes to the data.

If this is not feasible (e.g. due to very large quantities of data) you will have to go with custom migration and modify all invalid data accordingly via the migration rules you set up.